# Calculate all combinations of list when order doesn't matter

Tags: scala, combinatorics

I have a List[String], and i want to create a list of all possible pair combinations when order doesn't matter, i.e. ("a", "b") and ("b", "a") are the same combination.

For example:

```
val List = ("a", "b", "c")
```

The result I expect is:

```
List[List[String]] = List(List(a, b), List(a, c), List(b, c))
```

Thanks

Comment: You should use multisets (or sets if all values are unique), not lists, if the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `combinations` method does this. Your `List` value is actually a tuple though so define as a `List` as I did below.

```
scala> val list = List("a","b","c")
list: List[String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> list.combinations(2)
res0: Iterator[List[String]] = non-empty iterator

scala> list.combinations(2).toList
res1: List[List[String]] = List(List(a, b), List(a, c), List(b, c))
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the collections API, and you'd get this:

```
List("a", "b", "c").combinations(2).toList
```